# Cross reference items inside a figure using `svg` package?

Tags: cross-referencing, svg

Is it possible to cross reference items *inside* a figure using the `svg` package?

## EDIT

Here's an explanation of what I'm looking for. Suppose I have an SVG which when rendered looks like the following:

[image]

In LaTeX, I'd like to be able to do the following:

```
Item \ref{svgItem:red-circle} shown in Figure \ref{fig:svg-figure} is a red circle.

Item \ref{svgItem:green-circle} shown in Figure \ref{fig:svg-figure} is a green circle.
```

And get it to render in the PDF as follows:

```
Item 1 in Figure 1 is a red circle
Item 4 in Figure 1 is a green circle.
```

I would have thought this to be self-explanatory, but I hope this clarifies it better.

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a minimal working example that shows what kind of set up you intend to use.

Comment: Yes it is. See `svg-example.svg` at https://ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/svg/source/examples

Answer (score 2):

Still, no MWE.

Nevertheless, I assume you're looking for something like this:

```latex
\begin{filecontents}[noheader]{my-svg-example.svg}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g>
  <text>Package svg: \MakeLinkTarget*{svgitem:foo}\LaTeX{} target</text>
  </g>
</svg>
\end{filecontents}

\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\includesvg{my-svg-example.svg}
This is the link to something \hyperlink{svgitem:foo}{within the svg} picture.
\end{document}
```

So, if you want to make a reference to something within the svg picture, you would have to provide the desired link target as text.

**Edit/Clarification:**

In a simple SVG file, there are no magically created targets that can be referenced by LaTeX. Instead, these must be created manually or automatically by the user in the SVG file at the appropriate places. For this purpose, `\MakeLinkTarget*{<target>}` or `\MakeLinkTarget[<prefix>]{<counter>}` can be used, among others.

[hyperref-linktarget.pdf and hyperref-doc.pdf](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc)

Comment: That's a hyperlink. I'm looking for a reference as indicated in my original post.

Comment: Well, you did not provide a mwe as requested. Nevertheless, I created one. And as you are obviously not willing to pay some effort by your own, I won't do it either. My example gives you everything you need to figure out, how to achieve your goal. Just have a look at `hyperref`'s `\refstepcounter`

Comment: @mrpriggi This is a Q&A website. My question explicitly asks about references and your answer generates a hyperlink instead, so I can't accept it as the right answer. As for a MWE, what additional information were you missing that you wanted me to provide?

Comment: MWE stands for minimal working example so that anyone who is willing to help has least effort as possible in order to get on the actual task. It would also show, what you already tried to solve your problem by yourself. And it can be adapted during the progress of finding a solution. So instead of complaining, you could start to work on the problem yourself and show the results. But since your question is not specific to package `svg` or SVG files in general but concerns the way creating references with LaTeX, you maybe should ask your question in another context. MWE recommended.

Comment: My question is specific to the `svg` package and SVG files in general. I don't have a MWE to share with you since I believe what I'm asking for is quite self-explanatory. If you disagree, then please clearly specify what information you think is missing, and I will gladly provide it. If you're unsure how to achieve references for SVGs in the way I describe with LaTeX, then I would argue that you aren't the right person to answer this question.

Comment: Well, I am the developer of `svg` package. Anyways, you have to create the targets for your references manually, meaning every "Item" in your svg file has to be defined as such. How otherwise should LaTeX be able to make a reference to a specific item? There is nothing like `svgItem:red-circle` in the created SVG file where LaTeX could refer to. So you should have a look in [hyperref-linktarget.pdf](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc) especially on `\MakeLinkTarget`